# Present perfect vs. Present Perfect Continuous: "We (have lived) have been living in Canada for 5 years."

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

I have heard sometimes people say:

> We have lived in Canada for 5 years.

It tells me they are still living in Canada.

> We have been living in Canada for 5 years.

But I have rarely heard people say the above in present perfect continuous.

Does it mean the same thing?

Comment: related: **[have lived vs have been living](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/have-lived-vs-have-been-living)**